# PHP 8.0.7 password_verify terminates with error

Tags: php

I'm making a dummy login page for a school project, and I'm using a hardcoded login for testing.
However, when I execute the following page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<?php
$email = $password  = "";
$loginErr = $loginSuccess = "";

// Dummy login to replace the database
$correctEmail = htmlspecialchars("abc123@gmail.com");

$correctPassword =
    "\$2y\$10\$Ul2c6wZYxmO9MCJEnySdT.VnoRz7gAFOGVrAEOAhTFBM/5mp81Xl2";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]);
    $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"]);
    echo gettype($password);
    echo gettype($correctPassword);
    echo password_verify($password, $correctPassword) or die("Something went wrong");
```

I get the following output:

stringstringSomething went wrong

I get this output regardless of whether I escape-code the dollar signs in the hash.

When I tried to fetch the exception:

```
try
    {
        echo password_verify($password, $correctPassword);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) { echo $e->getMessage();}
```

it didn't print anything.

php -l returned no syntax errors for either version of the code.
As stated in the title, I'm using PHP 8.0.7, which should support password_verify according to the function's manual page.

Do any of you know how I can get this function working?

EDIT/SOLUTION: I assumed the function wasn't returning because "echo verify_password($password, $correctPassword)" didn't echo a false value. I now know that I have to typecast false values to int if I want them to show up.

Second, I thought that if the hash was of htmlspecialchars([password here]), then using htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"]) would be fine. Removing htmlspecialchars from the equation entirely fixed the issue.

Comment: Why do you assume this is an error and not just `password_verify` returning `false` because the password doesn't match?  What have you done to validate that the password is correct?  What happens when you use `password_hash` on the entered password and compare the hashes manually?

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($password, $correctPassword);` before your `password_verify()` line?

Comment: Use single quotes, then you won't need to escape anything.

Comment: Don't use `htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"])`.

Comment: I assumed that if the function had returned false, then "echo password_verify($password, $correctPassword)" would have printed a false value. Typecasting it to int made it appear.
Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem originates from your use of `htmlspecialchars()`. `htmlspecialchars()` is used for encoding certain characters that have meaning in HTML before sending them to the browser. It has no place here.

So, working from your code I set this up on my development server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
<body>


<?php
$email = $password  = "";
$loginErr = $loginSuccess = "";

// Dummy login to replace the database
$correctEmail = "abc123@gmail.com";

$correctPassword =
    '$2y$10$PxZQRBaAG81cH1BCJowrxu7RaNnlm1i.Ls0l95ohU9rvsqqZr3guG';

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    echo gettype($password);
    echo gettype($correctPassword);
    echo password_verify($password, $correctPassword) or die("Something went wrong");
} else {
    ?>
    <form method="POST">
        <input name="email"><br>
        <input name="password" type="password">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
<?php
}
```

I've added a basic form for testing and changed the correct password hash to a hash of 'password', and I've removed the references to `htmlspecialchars()`.

It works fine.

If you're using `htmlspecialchars()` as an attempt to defend against SQL injection, you've chosen the wrong function.

The quick fix would be to change to using `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. However, this is not considered best practice, and you should look to refactor your code to use prepared statements when no sanitisation is required at all.